# Why does my program not use the correct version of ITextSharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I’m using Microsoft Visual Developer 2010 Express, MVC 3, C#.  I’ve installed ITextSharp version 5.1.3 using the Package Manager Console. When I run my program I get a message that says:

> “Could not load file or assembly 'itextsharp, Version=10.0.0.0….”

I click on the itextsharp under References in my project.  The Object Browser has two versions of ITextSharp.  The first one is version 10.0.0.0.  The second one is version 5.1.3.  My guess is that the program looks at Version 10.0.0.0 first because it’s first on the list.  I tried to uninstall version 10.0.0.0 using the console but it can’t be found.

Questions:  Is there an iTextSharp version 10.0.0. out there?  I couldn’t find one.  I found a site that says that version 5.1.3 is the latest.

How can I uninstall version 10.0.0.0 if it is on my system and shouldn’t be there?

Here’s the code that cause the error:

```
byte[] buffer = standardPdfRenderer.Render(htmlText, pageTitle);
```

Comment: According to the iTextSharp Sourceforge page (http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/), the latest version is 5.1.3 as of November 30th, 2011.  As for the 10.0.0.0 version, can you simply remove it from the references instead of trying to uninstall it?

Comment: The problrem is only one instance is in references.  When I click on it I see both versions in the Object Brawser.  I don't know of any other way to remove it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the references to iTextSharp, right click the Project on the Solution explorer and and select "Clean" and then rebuild the solution to see whether the issue goes away.
Also make sure you don't have reference to the Version=10.0.0.0…. added in your Web.Config.

Comment: Thanks that seems to have done it.  In the Object Browser I noticed that one of them was all lowercase (itextsharp) and thei other (iTextSharp).  I used the console to uninstall both versions even though it reported that the second one did not exist.  I think the cleaning did the trick.  Thanks.